# Can't texture paint in cycles

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to use texture painting with UV maps (both of which I am new to), and when I go into texture paint for my model, I can't paint it. I have UV-unwrapped the model when in edit mode with smart unwrap, set the texture node as active in the node editor, and selected my image file. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: You are in *texture paint mode*, right?

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, I am.

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible you could you upload your .blend?

Comment: Figured it out. The model somehow got inverted.

Comment: Aha! Glad you figured it out. Feel free to add an answer using the answer button, this makes it easier for other people and search engines to find the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Landscape meshes are created with inverted normals. I inverted the normals back on the left sidebar. Afterward I was free to paint.